# How to query inside JSON array in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a column named data in my table Engine as JSON array.

```json
 [
        {
            "operation": "U",
            "taxCode": "1000",
            "description": "iva description",
            "tax": "12"
        },
        {
            "operation": "U",
            "taxCode": "1001",
            "description": "iva description",
            "tax": "12"
        },
        {
            "operation": "U",
            "taxCode": "1002",
            "description": "iva description",
            "tax": "12"
        }
    ]
```

I need to get the operation and desc value from this

The query which I formed is

```
select Id, data.operation, data.description 
from Engine,
     jsonb_to_recordset(Engine.data) as data(operation text, description text)
```

When I am running this query I'm getting error like no function matches the given name and argument type. you might need to add explicit type cast.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me in this. I am new to postgres.

Comment: The data type of engine .data is json

Comment: Then you need to use `json_to_recordset` not `jsonB_to_recordset`

Comment: I tried that also but I am getting an error  cannot call json_to_recordset on an object

Comment: Then your column doesn't contain an array

Comment: Thanks for your response. json_to_recordset is working fine now.

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-query-a-json-array-of-objects-as-a-recordset-in-postgresql-a81acec9fbc5

Comment: Is it possible to check null condition